# Meteor event for subscriber of collection for new insert of document in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a question regarding when a new document is added to mongodb

I have an order object that can be added server side after a meteor method call.

I have an admin page called ‘incomingOrders' subscribing to all orders.

What i would like to do , is just play a sound when on this page , when a new order is inserted into the database.

my client side collection updates with the new order, but i need it to show some sort of alert (i.e. alert box, sound , flashing screen!!!)

How would i exactly do this? 
is there an event that can that is triggerd when a new document is inserted that i can subscribe to?

I have no code tested as i don’t have any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

So i found the answer to my question

I used the `cursor.observe` function to observer when a document is added to my collection.

```
Template['incomingOrders'].helpers({
 orders:function(){
var cursor = Orders.find({},{sort: {createdAt: -1}});

 // watch the cursor for changes
var handle = cursor.observe({
  added:function(order){
    if(!initializing){
      console.log('order from handle');
      console.log(order);
      document.getElementById('xyz').play();
    }
  }
});

    return cursor;
  }


});
```

I have an initialising check (which is set to false in the rendered function of the template) as this function seems to be called on every element while the template is rendering . And then i simply call play on an audio element to alert me of a new document being added.

If there is a better way , please inform me!